# Expectation of energy-based model

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, generative-models

An energy-based model parametrized by $\theta$ is defined as
$$
p(x; \theta) \propto \exp(-f(x; \theta))
$$
For my specific case, it is that $f(x; A, y) = - \langle x, Ax \rangle - \langle x, y \rangle$ and $x$ is over the hypercube $\{ -1, +1 \}^N$.

I am looking for an efficient way of computing the expected value (barycenter) of this model **without MCMC/sampling**. Is it possible to do so?